# What is the standard way to move from springboot 1.5.8 to Springboot 2.7.17

Tags: spring, spring-security, migration

I have the task of migrating a service from springboot 1.5.8 to springboot 2.7.17. I changed the various versions across the different libs. But at run time, it shows missing errors, for some of the errors, i had to change the autoconfigure version back to 1.5.8, which i dont want to do. Now it is complaining

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193)
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106)
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at com.teamapt.SettlementReconApplication.main(SettlementReconApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324)
    ... 25 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please is there no way to change a springboot version and all the depenencies change too. I have missed my deadlines, I keep moving from one error to the other,

From property resolver error (which i know does not exist anymore in springboot 2, but why is it looking for it), to GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [****]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:612) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:815) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:783) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at com.teamapt.SettlementReconApplication.main(SettlementReconApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:203) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.7.17.jar:2.7.17]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:699) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1013) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:340) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:371) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:602) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    ... 19 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please, I am a first time, I might have broken some rules, but please I need this help, I have searched all of stack overflow, i could not find an answered question that speaks to my error. But if you find, please drop link.

I want springboot to simply use the new versions that i stated in my pom.xml

NB: I am editing the question to contain my pom.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <artifactId>settlementrecon</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.17</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <archiva.url>....</archiva.url>
        <activiti.version>6.0.0</activiti.version>
        <cosmos.contol.lib.version>2.0</cosmos.contol.lib.version>
        <cosmos.contol.redis.version>2.0</cosmos.contol.redis.version>
        <cosmos.audit.lib.version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</cosmos.audit.lib.version>
        <cosmos.audit.listener.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</cosmos.audit.listener.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.6.15.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.7.17</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.30</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.15.3</jackson.version>
        <gson.version>2.10.1</gson.version>
        <org.json.version>20231013</org.json.version>
        <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>
        <json-path.version>2.8.0</json-path.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>2.2</snakeyaml.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version> <!-- Jakarta EE version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.24.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- SPRING -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
     </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.70</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                    <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>


                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>11.1.0.2</version>
                </dependency>


                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.21</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
                    <version>2.70.0</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                            <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-transcoder -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>4.5.13</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.7</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.224</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- TEAMAPT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/graphql-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
            <version>21.3</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>cosmos-control-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${cosmos.contol.lib.version}</version>
            <classifier>lib</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>cosmos-control-redis-session</artifactId>
            <version>${cosmos.contol.redis.version}</version>
            <classifier>lib</classifier>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>token-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>atps-integration-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>audit-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>audit-listener</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-domain-bootsrapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>pos-merchant-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /TEAMAPT -->


        <!-- ACTIVITI -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>touchpoint-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>file-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>profectus-settlementrecon-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>profectus-settlementrecon-activiti-task</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>profectus-transactions-matching-ops</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
            <artifactId>profectus-notification-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.2.jre11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- /END ACTIVITI -->

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>archiva</id>
            <name>Archiva Repository</name>
            <url>${archiva.url}</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva</id>
            <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
            <url>${archiva.url}</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva</id>
            <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
            <url>${archiva.url}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>8.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>


    </build>

    <profiles>


        <profile>
            <id>...</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>zenith</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pos-settlementrecon-zenith-activiti-task</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>profectus-cba-lib-zenith</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>profectus-notification-lib-zenith</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.teamapt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>token-lib-zenith</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>...</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>


    </profiles>


</project>
```

Comment: Take small steps, do 2.0, 2.1 etc upto 2.7. Don't jump to 2.7 at once. Read the migration guides of the various versions.Don't mix versions of a framework as that will lead to trouble (which is what you have now).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response, Please I am not able to spot any version mismatch, I have also edited the question to include my pom.xml file.

Comment: The fact that you are manually managing that many dependencies is also worring, another thing is all the excludes, you shouldn't need it. You don't need the `spring-boot-dependencies` in the dependency management section as you already have the parent. If you need that many excludes you are generally doing it wrong. You are also using some ancient Spring Security JWT version which definitlivly pull in old dependencies.

Comment: The version of Activity you are using is build for Spring Boot 1.2, so I doubt it will still work with Spring Boot 2.7. I'm not even sure if there is a replacement for that. You are using a lot of dependencies and you need to figure out which versions of Spring / Spring Boot are supported by those libraries. You might need to upgrade those as well.

Comment: Yes @M.Deinum I think the activiti.* seem to be the issue. I tried excluding the various spring dependencies from it. 
I inherited this codebase and due to some vulnerabilities, we are forced to upgrade to springboot 2, could there be a way to manage the activity along with springboot w..

Comment: I doubt it as it is for Spring Boot 1.2 which is for the 4.x line of Spring, Spring Boot 2.x is for the Spring 5.x line. A lot of things changed, removed in that. So I doubt that is compatible, you will probably need to figure out what to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

I found an open source code for org.activiti from [github](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/releases/tag/8.0.0) which was built for java 17 and springboot 3.I adapted it to springboot 2.7.17 and built locally. I made a few changes to some part of my code. I have been able to move